# reset count above max time interval, in Rx count-based aggregation

Tags: c#, .net, linq, system.reactive

#### Count-based filtering without a time constraint

```
IObservable filteredStream = changes.Buffer(3);
```

#### How to introduce inactivity reset?

[image]

*But how to introduce a timeout `TimeSpan tooLong` so that the counting would restart from zero whenever the interval between two values exceeds this maximum?*

Comment: good question, interesting subject, image... the only thing missing is a freehand circle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is what you're after.

```
var longGap = source.Throttle(tooLong);
var filtered = source
  .Window(() => { return longGap; })  // Gives a window between every longGap
  .Select(io => io.Buffer(maxItems).Where(l => l.Count == maxItems))
  .Switch();  // Flattens the IObservable<IObservable<IList>> to IObservable<IList>
```

Comment: You should not use var when the right side does not express the return type of the expression.

Comment: @sweaver2112 I disagree with your statement. There is no hard and fast rule where this is concerned (style guidelines or otherwise).

Comment: @AndersonImes: abusing var makes the code less readable and increases comprehension time for the next guy - you disagree?

Comment: @sweaver2112 For Rx I think that the type doesn't really give you much information, filter, where, throttle, etc... all keep the same type despite completely changing the semantics.

Comment: @AndersonImes: saying the type doesn't give you much information is absurd.  To each his own however, personally I'm staying with Skeet, and I quote: "Personally I don't tend to use it if the type isn't reasonably obvious"

Comment: @sweaver2112 It's the job of the IDE to provide sufficient hints as to typing. var is way more malleable if you work with amplified types. Unless you're using vi, there's no need to set up your preferences as rules.

Comment: @sweaver2112: I think my objection to your comment was that you presented it as fact, rather than opinion. The use of the var keyword is about preference at the moment. I don't find it detrimental at all, especially when using things like Rx or Linq. You might disagree (this is great, actually), but I would be clear on a learning site like StackOverflow that your comments are based on opinion rather than fact. It tends to confuse issues.

Comment: @AndersonImes: i just think it can be abused by lazy programmers, for the reasons I mentioned. Everything I say should be taken as opinion. :)

Comment: @sweaver2112: sure, but it has its place. For example, if you do an expression that returns an anonymous type. What is the use of knowing that `myStuff.Select(thing => new { Name = thing.Name, Color = thing.Color } )` is of type `IEnumerable<a'>`? How do you even determine this without hints in the IDE? I don't think var is always about being lazy.